# Find real roots (if any) of the given Equation

Tags: calculus

Find real roots (if any) of equation:
$${{{(2x^2-2)(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4-2x^2+1}+(6x^2-2)(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4-2x^2+1}(2x^3-2x)\left(2x\cdot \sqrt{x^4-2x^2+1}+\frac{(x^2+1)(4x^3-4x)}{2\cdot \sqrt{x^4-2x^2+1}}\right)}}\over  {{(x^2+1)^2(x^4-2x^2+1)}}}=0$$

After simplification,

$${{{2(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4-2x^2+1}+4x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^2-1)^2+4x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)}} \over {{(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)}}}=0$$

How to find real roots?

Comment: Note that the term in the square root is $(x^2+1)^2$, and then factor everything out.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplyfy this expression even further:

$$\frac{2(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^4-2x^2+1}+4x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^2-1)^2+4x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)}=0$$
$$\frac{2(x^2+1)[\sqrt{x^4-2x^2+1}+2x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2-1)^2+2x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^2-1)]}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)}=0$$

Now we assume $x\neq \pm 1$ and notice that $\frac{2(x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2-1)}$ cannot be $0$. We also notice that $\sqrt{x^4-2x^2+1}=\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2}=|x^2-1|$.

$$|x^2-1|+2x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2-1)^2+2x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2+1)(x^2-1)=0$$
$$|x^2-1|+2x^2(3x^2-1)(x^2-1)[(x^2-1)+(x^2+1)]=0$$
$$|x^2-1|+4x^4(3x^2-1)(x^2-1)=0$$

We see that $x=\pm 1$ is a solution. Dividing by $x^2-1$ will result in 
$$1+4x^4(3x^2-1)=0$$
for $|x|>1$ and 
$$-1+4x^4(3x^2-1)=0$$ 
for $|x|<1$

The first Equation has no solutions as $3x^2-1\geq 3\cdot 1-1=2$. Thus, $1+4x^4(3x^2-1)>1$.

The second equation has solutions but they are only obtainable from the cubic equation. You could also try to calculate them numerically using Newton's Method.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$a/b = 0$ if and only if $a = 0$, so suffices to only consider the numerator. What about factoring that complex expression? You can take some terms out, update your question with further work and will be gald to give more hints.